# Cache problème with $resource on IE

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, caching, resources

In my app, i use $resource in order to get json resource from server.

With IE, it seems that data are cached.
Is there a great way to prevent this ? (i prefere not use a random number into my request).
Can i configure something like this ?

```
app.config(['$resourceProvider', function ($resourceProvider) {
    // something to prevent cache
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems with a filter into my java server side.
he look like this :

```
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse rep = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        rep.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        rep.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        rep.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}

}
```

I don't know if it's possible to do something like this with angular.